# String with char pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

When I have an uninitialized pointer I can not put into it because there is no memory allocation place!

When I have a pointer that points to a variable of type char and I want to put into it with %s, the program lets me put up two characters (2 bytes) and beyond that prints me an error.

My question is why it is can be put into two letters when char can hold only one byte? Is the program should not fall even two letters?

Comment: Can you post an example? If you're invoking undefined behavior, you shouldn't be surprised when weird things happen.

Comment: Char only stores one letter.

Comment: But `char*` often points to a buffer. So we need more info what he is doing. He mentions `%s`, so I assume something like `sprintf` is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be related to alignment. If there is a multibyte type following a char variable, there may be a small number of unused bytes inbetween but you can not depend on this as it is clearly undefined.

I would suggest using  `valgrind` to check for memory problems rather than depending on observation.

Comment: If there is a multibyte variable following, then writing more than two chars would simply overwrite parts of that variable, but not cause a crash. Not a very likely scenario, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, this is undefined behaviour. Writing to a pointer which does not point to allocated memory might work or might crash. I would consider the code buggy, even it if it does not crash for the first two characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the behaviour of your program is due to the fact that you have not initialised
the pointer with any block of address in memory.
By default the pointer may or not have a valid memory address.

Try this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *_str = malloc(x); // x is the number of bytes that you want to point to.
    fgets(_str, x, stdin);
    printf("\n_str = %s", _str);
    return 0;
}
```